# Office 365 Authorization without login

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, oauth, token

I am developing a Mobile app which sends data to SharePoint list (SharePoint Online, Office 365). The users of the app should be able to save data in the list silently, without logging. Is this possible to do? Could you please share some ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could create a user account, and hard code the credentials for that user into your app.  This is unwise, however, since you would not be able to track who does what.  Why can't your users login?

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible, as wjervis mentions in the comment, but unwise. You won’t be able to track user activity and the user have no idea which items where edited by herself. You would destroy the authentication and authorization to your SharePoint Online list and could, if the app got into the wrong hands, be a major security breach.

I would strongly suggest that the user signs in with her Office 365 account details, and uses those for the list.